# Postgres invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc3 0x2f

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, utf-8

I work with a payment API and it returns some XML. For logging I want to save the API response in my database.

One word in the API is "manhã" but the API returns "manh�". Other chars like á ou ç are being returned correctly, this is some bug in the API I guess.

But when trying to save this in my DB I get:

```
Postgres invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc3 0x2f
```

How can I solve this?

I tried things like

`response.encode("UTF-8")` and also `force_encode` but all I get is:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)
```

I need to either remove this wrong character or convert it somehow.

Comment: Are you sure that "a payment API" is giving you UTF-8 at all?

Comment: @AmigoJack the api returns a XML in ISO-8859-1. My rails table field is a normal "character varying". I have other APIs that return UTF-8 and I need to store them all in the same column. So I need to convert the API response in some way to be able to save it in the DB.

Comment: The XML starts like this: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>"

Comment: It should be obvious: `ISO-8859-1` is a different encoding than `UTF-8` - you have to convert one to the other instead of passing it thru unhandled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re on the right track - you should be able to solve the problem with the `encode` method - when the source encoding is known you should be able to simply use:

```rb
response.encode(‘UTF-8’, ‘ISO-8859-1’)
```

There may be times where there are invalid characters in the source encoding, and to get around exceptions, you can instruct ruby how to handle them:

```rb
# This will transcode the string to UTF-8 and replace any invalid/undefined characters with ‘’ (empty string)
response.encode(‘UTF-8’, 'ISO-8859-1', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ‘’)
```

This is all laid out in the [Ruby docs for String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-encode) - check them out!

—--

Note, many people incorrectly assume that `force_encode` will somehow fix encoding problems.  `force_encode` simply tags the string as the specified encoding - it does **not** transcode and replace/remove the invalid characters.  When you're converting between encodings, you must transcode so that characters in one character set are correctly represented in the other character set.

As pointed out in the comment section, you can use `force_encoding` to transcode your string if you used: `response.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')` (which is equivalent to the first example using `encode` above).

Comment: The source encoding **is known** and it has no invalid sequences - there should neither be the need to "drop", nor to force something. Just convert it and let exceptions occur, as none are expected.

Comment: `force_encoding` will help: `response.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')` for example.

Comment: @muistooshort - yes, you can use force_encoding in that way, my point was more that people use `force_encoding` thinking that it will somehow transcode the string when all it does it change what encoding the string is tagged as.  I'll update the post for clarity around this point.  Thanks!

@AmigoJack - Good call - when both source/dest encodings are known, you shouldn't have to specify the replacement options.  Of course, assuming the encoding is valid in the source encoding.  I'll update the answer with a bit more context.